# How do I check if I have a C compiler on my windows PC?

Tags: c, windows, installation, terminal, windows-terminal

I want to start creating programs in C, so I installed the VSCode C/C++ extension, but then the guide (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) says that I also need a compiler. It says to check for one first:

Checking for the GCC compiler g++:

```
g++ --version
```

Checking for the Clang compiler clang:

```
clang --version
```

But when I execute those in the VSCode terminal (or even in the windows terminal) like this I get an error:

```
C:\Users\15Z-DB000>clang --version
'clang' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Is something missing from my terminal or windows? Or am I using the wrong terminal? In which directory am I even supposed to execute those commands? I also encountered similar issues before but it never bothered me until now. What else can I do?

If you have some other guides/recommendations for IDE's/compilers then feel free to list them as well.

Comment: You need to install either `gcc` or `clang` too. One way could be to install [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/) and then install `gcc` with  `pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc`

Comment: On most UNIX operating systems, such as Linux, it is common for a C compiler such as gcc and/or clang to be pre-installed. That is why on these operating systems, you should check which compiler you already have installed before making a decision to install another C compiler. However, on Microsoft Windows operating sytems, it is very uncommon for a C compiler to be pre-installed. Therefore, you would probably know if you had a C compiler installed on your computer, and if you know nothing about it, you can be reasonably certain that you don't already have one installed.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanations. I was worried that something was wrong with my windows cuz I had similar issues before, but if that's the case then I don't think I have anything to worry about. I'll continue with the installation.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum. It is a place for asking specific questions and getting specific answers, which may also be useful to other readers. Therefore, when asking a question, you should limit your question to one specific question which can be answered by one specific answer. By additionally asking for "guides/recommendations for IDE's/compilers", you are asking several questions inside the same question, which violates the rules/guidelines of the site.

Comment: Also, questions asking for software recommendations or for recommendations for off-site resources [are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Therefore, your question will likely be closed unless you fix it with an [edit].